# Composer Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running

Tags: php, composer-php, self-updating

When I try to run in the first time composer install i get :

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 file could not be downloaded: SSL operation fail
  ed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

I think i must update my composer but if i run composer self-update i get this Exception: 
[RuntimeException]
  SHA384 is not supported by your openssl extension, could not verify the phar file integrity

The result of my compser diagnose it's OK except:

Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "C:\Applications\bin\composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.

Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license

Checking composer version: WARNING
You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (edece864e7e4c668dcad6601df70777882d22116 => 1.10.6)

Please Help me.

Comment: Yes, i solved this probleme by installing a new version of composer Command-line installation by steps in : https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: or either you can update using this command as well `composer self-update`